# Windows freezes when formatting a USB as a virtual box

Tags: windows, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to format a USB on Windows 10. When I try and format the USB Windows freezes? I'm also doing this on Windows in a Virtual Box, with a MacBook Pro (2015 intel i7) running Monterey as the host for the Virtual Box.

I have already done the following;

- installed the virtual box extension pack (with matching version to my virtual box)
- added the USB as a filter in Settings > Ports > USB
- ejected disk on macOS and then started Windows Virtual box - issue persists

Windows is able to see the drive and I'm able to pass files back to/from the USB on both macOS and Windows, but I'm not able to format the drive on the Windows side still?

Comment: A USB what? Pendrive? Hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

One general thing that can help with Windows 10/11 freezing is turning off the PCI Express setting under Power Options settings -> Change Advanced power settings.

USB is related to PCI.